# Android localDB and serverDB synchronization

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing one app which will also work in offline mode when internet is not available. In offline mode user save his data in android localDB(sqlite). As soon as internet is available, I will start synchronization of Android localDB(sqlite) with my serverDB. Is there any best way to achieve this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I have same synchronization in one of my application.

I use first send data to server via web service, 
then reset my db and get latest data from server via web service..

Answer (score 0):

I synchronise highcore data kept on server with some 5K mobile devices.  Each highscore entry has timestamp generated by server when it arrives from device.  Mobile device knows latest timestamp of highscore entries it already has seen, and requests entries from server with bigger timestamp only.